# Getting the last ID value w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a number of form text fields on a page. Each field has a unique numerical ID. How can i check what if the latest ID? For example, if I have 7 text fields, when i execute on click jQuery function I need to be able to know that the last ID was 7 in order to increment it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `:last` selector like so:

```
$('.someClass') // All the elements
$('.someClass:last') // Just the last element
```

You can then simply query that object for it's Id.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    var lastfieldsid = $('#fieldwrapperid input').last().attr('id');
    //do evil things here
});
```

I'd love to hear more about what you're trying to do here.  Generally modifying unique ID attributes is not really necessary.  If you need to store data in your DOM, use the html5-compliant attributes that follow the form `data-something="someval"`.  That way you're not modifying a core HTML attribute (ID) to do something that sounds kind of wonky.

```
<fieldset id="fieldwrapperid">
    <input type="text" data-someid="10" />
    <input type="text" data-someid="11" />
    <input type="text" data-someid="12" />
    etc
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I am adding cloning form field with jQuery but they all must have unique IDs for my code to work.

Comment: Right, it's that dependency on them having a unique ID that I'm worried about.  Yes, elements need to have unique IDs, but when you're dynamically adding elements and trying to reference them in this manner, you've likely got a design flaw that's making your life more difficult than it needs to be.  Why do they need IDs at all?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[type=text]:last").attr("id");
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try    `$("form").find(":input[type=='text']").size()`